# Regex to exclude words followed by a single quote

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I am very new to regexp and tried to create a pattern for a NSRegularExpression. I want to extract, anywhere in a given string, all the full words that correspond to a keyword, but only if this keyword isn't followed by a single quote.

For the "bill" keyword, I need to extract in my string any occurrence of

```
bill
bill,
bill!

but not

bill's
billy
billboard
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick.

```
NSString *pattern = @"\\bbill\\b(?!')";
```

Regular Expression:

```
\b             the boundary between a word char (\w) and not a word char
 bill          'bill'
\b             the boundary between a word char (\w) and not a word char
(?!            look ahead to see if there is not:
  '            '\''
)              end of look-ahead
```

However, place you keyword data or variable in your pattern.

```
\\bKEYWORD\\b(?!')
```

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/uB5oQ5)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it matches what I need. I tried that before at several places and it didn't work since I had a bad formatted pattern in one instance... It works also to extract the s from bill's ;-) Thanks again!

Comment: And how could it from this list: That's (e.g., a quote followed by one or several letters) That', (e.g., a quote followed by punctuation mark) That' (e.g., a quote followed by a space) That... to extract the selection: That's (inchanged) That' (punctuation mark removed) That' (following space not removed) That (unchanged) –

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is ok: `\bbill\b(?!')`
keyworlds: \w 
           (?!exp)